# Stratified sampling on factor

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

I have a dataset of 1000 rows with the following structure:

```
     device geslacht leeftijd type1 type2
1       mob        0       53     C     3
2       tab        1       64     G     7
3        pc        1       50     G     7
4       tab        0       75     C     3
5       mob        1       54     G     7
6        pc        1       58     H     8
7        pc        1       57     A     1
8        pc        0       68     E     5
9        pc        0       66     G     7
10      mob        0       45     C     3
11      tab        1       77     E     5
12      mob        1       16     A     1
```

I would like to make a sample of 80 rows, composed of 10 rows with type1 = A, 10 rows with type1 = B, and so on. Is there anyone who can help he?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(split(df, df$type1), function(i)
          i[sample(1:nrow(i), size = 10, replace = TRUE),]))
```

**EDIT:**

Other solutions suggested by @BrodieG

```
with(DF, DF[unlist(lapply(split(seq(type), type), sample, 10, TRUE)), ])

with(DF, DF[c(sapply(split(seq(type), type), sample, 10, TRUE)), ])
```

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I would approach this using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[sample(.N, 10, replace = TRUE)], by = type1]$V1
df[indx]
#     device geslacht leeftijd type1 type2
#  1:    mob        0       45     C     3
#  2:    mob        0       53     C     3
#  3:    tab        0       75     C     3
#  4:    mob        0       53     C     3
#  5:    tab        0       75     C     3
#  6:    mob        0       45     C     3
#  7:    tab        0       75     C     3
#  8:    mob        0       53     C     3
#  9:    mob        0       53     C     3
# 10:    mob        0       53     C     3
# 11:    mob        1       54     G     7
#...
```

Or a simpler version would be

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[sample(.N, 10, replace = TRUE)], by = type1]
```

Basically we are sampling (with replacement- as you have less than 10 rows within each group) from the row indexes within each group of `type1` and then subsetting the data by this index

---

Similarly with `dplyr` you could do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(type1) %>%
  sample_n(10, replace = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option in base R:

```
df[as.vector(sapply(unique(df$type1), 
                    function(x){
                        sample(which(df$type1==x), 10, replace=T)
                    })), ]
```